# Fixing Signal 13 (SIGPIPE) error for find and grep pipeline

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep, find, signals

I have a situation where I'm trying to install software into my system.

I'm using a fakeroot approach to install them in a separate directory where I'm listing all the files, directories and links they install into three files `FILES`, `DIRS`, `LINKS`.

Then I'm using find to get SHA1 hashes of all files in a file named `sha1sums`. I don't want the hash of the file `sha1sums` itself. So I used this command

```
 find . -type f -exec sha1sum {} \; | grep -ve "\./sha1sums$" >sha1sums
```

This worked fine. However when installing `kbd-2.0.3`, it threw a lot of lines of error-

```
 find: 'sha1sum' terminated by signal 13
```

I know signal 13 is the `SIGPIPE` signal ("Broken Pipe"). But I don't get two things:

1. Why is it happening with only this package?
2. This is probably being caused by `grep` closing the read pipe. But why is it closing it?

Comment: Do you see `grep` crashing with an error message? What's the exit status after that (`echo "$?"`)?

Answer (score 1):

I can't actually reproduce your issue with the GNU versions of all utilities that you use, nor with my native OpenBSD utilities. Could it be a bad disk?

However, rather than filtering out the `sha1sums` filename by piping through `grep`, you may omit calculating the SHA1 digest for that particular file altogether:

```
find . -type f ! -path './sha1sums' -exec sha1sum {} + >sha1sums
```

The negated `-path` test will remove the `./sha1sums` pathname from the list of pathnames passed to `sha1sum`.

Additionally, the utility will be called with as many filenames as possible in one go rather than once for each name, thanks to the `+` at the end.

Since this is not using a pipeline, there will be no `SIGPIPE` issue.